# how to detect phyisic collision in different class Sprite Kit

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit, game-physics

I have a class called Blade.h and I make A SKSpriteNode on that!
now I make new instance of that class on Main Class.

```
#import "Blade.h"

@implementation Blade

-(void) GenerateBalde
{
    SKSpriteNode *blade = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"blade"];
    [blade runAction:[SKAction rotateByAngle:M_PI duration:1]];
    [self addChild:blade];
}

@end
```

now, I want to have an instance of this object in my main class and I wanna detect the physic collision the Blade with another Sprites in my main class!
I know how to make an instance , but I wanna know how to detect the collision of different objects in different classes + physic!

please advice!

Answer (score 0):

It would be better if your `Blade` was a subclass of `SKSpriteNode` and then in its `init` method use:

```
if (self = [super initWithImageNamed:@"blade"]){
   //more code
}
return self;
```

Another solution is to use a property, so instead of creating a `SKSpriteNode` in `generateBlade` method use this:

In Blade.h add `@property (nonatomic, retain) SKSpriteNode *bladeSprite`.

In your `generateBlade` method, use this:

```
self.bladeSprite = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"blade"];
[self.bladeSprite runAction:[SKAction rotateByAngle:M_PI duration:1]];
[self addChild:self.bladeSprite];
```

Then, in your `MainScene`, in `update:` method, you can check the collision using this code:

```
-(void)update:(CFTimeInterval)currentTime {
    if (CGRectIntersectsRect(otherObject.frame, blade.bladeSprite.frame){
        //Collisioning!
    }
}
```

If you are using a `SKSpriteNode` subclass as mentioned in first lines, you could just do `blade.frame` instead of `blade.bladeSprite.frame` (you won't need to set a property).